# PHP - Conditional extraction of a string from within another?

Tags: php, string, substring

I need some help with PHP, as I'm very new to it.

I have these set of strings coming in from a location, and I need to conditionally extract a string subset from it, whenever its present.

**Set Up:**

Each string I get has these `Attributes`, and each `Attribute` has some `Values`. All `Attributes` are optional, and all `Attributes` can have a variable number of values.

The pattern of these strings is like this:

`... Attribute Name: Attribute Values Attribute Name: Attribute Values ...`

For example, here are a few example strings:

```
Attribute A: Value 1, Value 2 Attribute B: Value 3, Value 4, Value 5, Value 6 Attribute C: Value 7, Attribute D: Value 8, Value 9

Attribute A: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute B: Value 4, Value 5 Attribute C: Value 6, Value 7, Value 8, Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10, Value 11

Attribute B: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute C: Value 4 Attribute D: Value 5, Value 6, Value 7, Value 8 Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10
```

Notice that some strings have some `Attributes` missing, and all `Attributes` can have a variable number of `Values` listed next to it.

**The Issue:**

I want to extract all values of `Attribute D`, whenever `Values` for `Attribute D` are present.

So for example..

For input this string:

```
Attribute A: Value 1, Value 2 Attribute B: Value 3, Value 4, Value 5, Value 6 Attribute C: Value 7, Attribute D: Value 8, Value 9
```

I should get this output: `Value 8, Value 9`

For input this string:

```
Attribute A: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute B: Value 4, Value 5 Attribute C: Value 6, Value 7, Value 8, Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10, Value 11
```

I should get this output: An empty or null string, since `Attribute D` is not present in the input string

For input this string:

```
Attribute B: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute C: Value 4 Attribute D: Value 5, Value 6, Value 7, Value 8 Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10
```

I should get this output: `Value 5, Value 6, Value 7, Value 8`

---

I think a series of PHP ifs and string functions are needed here, but I'm wondering if someone can chalk up the conditional extraction code .. Will speed me up a lot :)

**Cooked up the code myself:**

I first break the string into substrings, using `:` as the delimiter. Then I go through each substring and search for `Attribute D` string. If found, I know that the next substring will have the values for `Attribute D`. Then I just remove the last word from this next substring (i.e. remove the next `Attribute's` name).

2 flaws in this code though (won't occur in my environment though) .. Hope you guys can find them :)

Here is the final code I used:

```
<?php

    $subStrings = explode(':',$product['description']);

    $arrayIndexContainingAttributeD = -1;

    $length = count($subStrings);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
      if(strpos($subStrings[$i], 'Attribute D') != false)
      {
        $arrayIndexContainingAttributeD = $i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }

    $attributeDStringAvailable = false;

    if($arrayIndexContainingAttributeD != -1 && $arrayIndexContainingAttributeD<$length)
    {
        $attributeDString = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $subStrings[$arrayIndexContainingAttributeD]);
        $attributeDStringAvailable = true;
    }

?>

<?php if ($attributeDStringAvailable == true) { ?>
<h3><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $attributeDString; ?></a></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The pattern is wrong .. I'll correct that now. Thats for pointing that out !

Comment: Is the `Attribute` word always present, or is this example? Can attributes have spaces and other white characters? The same questions about values.

Comment: If spaces are allowed how would you tell this string `Value 3 Attribute B` apart?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make this as self-explanatory as possible. Example:

```
$string = 'Attribute B: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute C: Value 4 Attribute D: Value 5, Value 6, Value 7, Value 8 Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10';
$query = 'D';
echo getAttributeValues($string, $query);

function getAttributeValues($string = '', $query = null) {
  if(!strpos($string, $query)) {
    echo 'attribute not in string';
  } else {
    $array = explode('Attribute ', $string);
    $attributes = array_filter($array);

    foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
      if(strpos($attribute, $query.':') !== false) {
        $return = str_replace($query.':', '', $attribute);
        return trim($return);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9w8-tn0

Comment: This won't really work though, because in the real examples, `Attribute` names don't start with "Attribute" necessarily ... Maybe I should have explained that too .. I did more or less the same thing, but exploded using `:`

Answer (score 0):

**Cooked up the code myself:**

I first break the string into substrings, using : as the delimiter. Then I go through each substring and search for Attribute D string. If found, I know that the next substring will have the values for Attribute D. Then I just remove the last word from this next substring (i.e. remove the next Attribute's name).

2 flaws in this code though (won't occur in my environment though) .. Hope you guys can find them :)

Here is the final code I used:

```
<?php

    $subStrings = explode(':',$product['description']);

    $arrayIndexContainingAttributeD = -1;

    $length = count($subStrings);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
      if(strpos($subStrings[$i], 'Attribute D') != false)
      {
        $arrayIndexContainingAttributeD = $i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }

    $attributeDStringAvailable = false;

    if($arrayIndexContainingAttributeD != -1 && $arrayIndexContainingAttributeD<$length)
    {
        $attributeDString = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $subStrings[$arrayIndexContainingAttributeD]);
        $attributeDStringAvailable = true;
    }

?>

<?php if ($attributeDStringAvailable == true) { ?>
<h3><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $attributeDString; ?></a></h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a single regex:

```
$string = 'Attribute A: Value 1, Value 2 Attribute B: Value 3, Value 4, Value 5, Value 6 Attribute C: Value 7, Attribute D: Value 8, Value 9

Attribute A: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute B: Value 4, Value 5 Attribute C: Value 6, Value 7, Value 8, Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10, Value 11

Attribute B: Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 Attribute C: Value 4 Attribute D: Value 5, Value 6, Value 7, Value 8 Attribute E: Value 9, Value 10';

preg_match_all('#Attribute D:\s*(.*?)(?:\s*(?:Attribute|$))#s', $string, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Value 8, Value 9
    [1] => Value 5, Value 6, Value 7, Value 8
)
```